# How to fix WSO2 "Error connecting to the Tryit ajax proxy"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am very new to WSO2 and I am working through the WSO2 example [Cloud to RDBMS using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/cloud-to-rdbms-using-wso2-esb/).  I have followed the example as closely as I can.  When I click "TryIt" for the service I am running into an "Error connecting to the Tryit ajax proxy"  I do have the axis2 server started with the command /opt/wso2esb-4.8.1/samples/axis2Server$ ./axis2server.sh and the axis2 server looks to be operating correctly.  Please let me know if the example is dated or if there is something else I need to do.  It is certainly missing steps that I have had to infer and I may have not known to take a step that it didn't explicitly tell me to take.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

-Joe

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by deleting artifacts from server and re-deploying (no other changes).